# Getting the index of an HTML element but filtering out clearfix divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a CMS and to save my text, I need to know the index of the element I am working in.

I have the following (stripped) piece of HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project" >
        <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561" >
            <div>
                <div class="content dummy-content" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
                    <div class="content" data-content="text">
                        <p>sdfas</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </article>
    <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project">
        <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561" >
            <div>
                <div class="content dummy-content" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
                    <div class="content" contenteditable="true" data-content="text">
                        <p>asfdsad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project">
        <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561">
            <div>
                <div class="content dummy-content" contenteditable="true" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
                <div class="content" style="line-height:21px;" contenteditable="true" data-content="text">
                    <p>asdfsd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>

    <!-- This one messes up the count -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project" >
        <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561">
            <div >
                <div class="content dummy-content" contenteditable="true" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
                <div class="content dummy-content" contenteditable="true" data-content="text">Dummy text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

The articles are the ones that matter, the clearfix div is just there to fix the clearance.

When I edit some text, I trigger a change event on the text that has been changed, and thus getting the `this` from that element:

```
var that = $(this);
```

I then go up to the `.project` closest element en count the index:

```
that.closest('.project').index();
```

But this of course also counts the `div.clearfix`.
I tried to resolve that by adding a selector to the index function:

```
that.closest('.project').index('.project');
```

But this still gave the wrong index.

Any ideas to get a correct count?

### EDIT

I am giving you not enough information. The above HTML example is just 1 element in a page.
There can be multiple elements like the above, divided by a container, div etc..

What appears to be the case here is that when you enter a selector into the `index`-function, it searches the entire document for this selector and then returns the index of that set.

I tried to solve this by inserting a set of nodes into the index functions:

```
var project = that.closest('.project');
project.index(project.siblings('.project'));
```

But this only returns -1

I created a workaround, but it's not what I was searching for:

```
index = project.index() - project.prevAll(':not(.project)').length;
```

If anyone has a correct way of using index here, please let me know!

Comment: `var $p = that.closest('.project'); var idx = $p.closest('.row').index($p)` ?

Comment: @Abayob do you want to get the index of a particular project within a row?

Comment: Yes I need the index of the article.project in the set beneath the row. That is mandatory! And I need to count only between the article.project elements, all the other elements between them are just for fixing/styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Array's `indexOf` on the `article.projects` elements and search for your specific one :

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  // get your targeted element
  var target = $(e.target).closest('.project')[0];
  // call indexOf on the list of all article.project elements, searching for your one
  var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call($('article.project'), target);

  $('#log').html('clicked on ' + index);

})
```

```css
#log{position: fixed; top:0; z-index: 99; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4); color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project">
    <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561">
      <div>
        <div class="content dummy-content" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
        <div class="content" data-content="text">
          <p>sdfas</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project">
    <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561">
      <div>
        <div class="content dummy-content" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
        <div class="content" contenteditable="true" data-content="text">
          <p>asfdsad</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project">
    <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561">
      <div>
        <div class="content dummy-content" contenteditable="true" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
        <div class="content" style="line-height:21px;" contenteditable="true" data-content="text">
          <p>asdfsd</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <!-- This one messes up the count -->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 project">
    <div class="inphos-hover-color-element5715e6986d561">
      <div>
        <div class="content dummy-content" contenteditable="true" data-content="title">Vul hier uw titel in</div>
        <div class="content dummy-content" contenteditable="true" data-content="text">Dummy text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to put an attribute (aka. the index) in each article tag. Like:

```
    // at the bottom of the page
    // or inside $(document).ready()

    var articles=$("article");
    for (var i=0; i<articles.length; i++)
        $(articles[i]).attr("index",i);

    /* result: 
    <article index="0" class=".... 
    <article index="1" class=".... 
    */
```

Then, when you detect the change in one article, you simply grab the index from the attribute of the article tag.

```
   // that = the current edited div
   var target_article=$(that).parent("article");
   var target_index=$(target_article).attr("index");
```

What do you think? A little demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cej45wn1/

Comment: I like your solution, but it is a workaround to prevent using the function index().